# using the value from one JSON as the key in another

Tags: node.js

I have 2 JSONs.  One contains data like:

```
const data = {
"dataElements": {
    "someField": "someData1",
    "someOtherField": "someOtherData"
},
"anotherDataElement": {
    "yetMoreFields": "evenMoreData",
    "stillMore": "dater"
}}
```

The other contains something like:

```
const lookUp = {
"lookUpValues": {
    "valueOne": "data.dataElements.someField",
    "someOtherField": "someOtherData"
}}
```

What I need to do is take the value of lookup.lookUpValues.valueOne (which would resolve to "data.dataElements.someField") and get that value from the data object ("someData1")

Comment: not sure if I'm understanding... but I'm guessing you cant do `object.something` because you don't know what `something` is right? then just call it with `object["something"]` where you can just replace with a string you're getting from the other object... does that help?

Comment: it would be great to add some a bit more detailed explanation with tiny code snippet showing the problem. For now it seems that to solve the issue you should get rid of quotes for data.dataElements.someField, bt it can't be so easy, right? You do not know the property name? Or the object name? Be a bit specific, please.

Comment: There is nothing built-into javascript to accomplish this, but there are a handful of utilities to handling this exact scenario. [lodash's `get()` method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) is one common choice. `_.get({ hello: { world: 1 }}, 'hello.world') // returns 1`

Comment: There isn't any trace of JSON in this question. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure, usually an object or an array (but primitive types like strings or numbers can also be represented as JSON). Its purpose is to be persisted or transferred through the network. When it is retrieved from persistence or received from the network it has to be parsed to get back a data structure similar to the one used to generate it. Your example contains two JavaScript objects and no JSON. (In code, a JSON is a string.)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript or Node.js does not provide any function to achieve your goal but you can write such a function yourself in several lines of code:

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
  // split the path in pieces separated by '.'
  const pieces = path.split('.');

  // walk the path, for each piece get the property with the same name from the current object
  return pieces.reduce(
    // result = the current object being walked
    // piece = the name of the current path piece
    // return the `piece` property of the `result` object (or `undefined` if it is not an object)
    (result, piece) => result instanceof Object ? result[piece] : undefined,
    // start walking with the provided object
    object
  );
}
```

Then call it like:

```js
const value = getValue(data, 'dataElements.someField');
```

Check it [online](https://tio.run/##jVE9T8MwEN39K05ZkkjFEmurwgJsKBMsiME419bFtSP7Ugmh/vZyttOoQwe2892793Heq6OKOpiB7pzv8ay9iwS9IgVr@BWQy2eLB3QUl7kDEP0BXwzafglVqp8Yc18t5llHOwzXgNxIqIoxpwRUzl96E/uF/Afp1YfCz4oVHtGlRl6fNMhYm3o8Zn8YMq04rYQo/q3332/DlKA83pUdcU5wTK/OTQRKXqeUc7z/R2Lt82Z0mox3sEXKao3/2qOmBQyKdm1WLvYGgxoj20sDGQdrqKll3a4YEZDG4CaIDNiPGptsowkYR5vo0qyF9QOUDhgmVU6j30CXJeFxGn1k7CcsYXQ9bozDvmQq1rhk0ZMQ@d@9RWn9tpn9l8stoL4@obzcrm5bcXMtHZOXbt@Ut85/).